# How can I change the first 5 characters of a string in python?

Tags: python

How can I change the first 5 characters of a string in python? Is there any library or method for this?

An example:

Input:

```
str1: ABCSDASFA213123
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
str2: XXXXXASFA213123
```

Comment: What did you try so far? any example of expected input/output??

Comment: May be worth noting, strings are immutable; you can reassign a variable to reference a new string (which may not be relevant to your concern).

Comment: Just added expected output here

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to update/replace characters in Python strings. Like [this one](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/python-replace-character-in-a-string-by-index-example-code/). Why are you asking here? Did you try any tutorials and they didn't work?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so in a strict sense, you cannot _change_ them.  The usual way to do this is to assemble a _new_ string that has the desired contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Slice off the first five characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/364696), and replace them with whatever you like:

```
new_str = 'X' * 5 + old_str[5:]
```

Comment: I didn't know we could do this `'X' * 5` in python. I appreciate your answer

Comment: @cosmos-1905-14: Yep, all sequences can be multiplied to produce that many repetitions of the sequence. I could've type `'XXXXX'`, but I kinda enjoy making the intended repetition count explicit when I can.